# GoLang program executing on single thread even with GOMAXPROCS(4)

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

In the following GoLang program, I am trying to implement the [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) for N men and N women, using 2*N goroutines (1 for each man and woman).

The program closely follows the program definition as each goroutine (read "each man") sends a message via channel to the desired woman goroutine who in turn rejects/accepts his proposal. I expected the program to easily be scheduled on multiple threads on setting `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)` however it still runs in (almost) the exact same time (and running linux command `time` still shows CPU usage at `100%` instead of expected `400%`)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

const N = 500

type human struct {
    pref    [N]int
    phone   chan int
    cur_eng int
    cur_num int
    id      int
}

var men = [N]human{}
var women = [N]human{}

func man(id int) {
    guy := &men[id]
    for {
        runtime.Gosched()
        for j := guy.cur_num + 1; j < N; j++ {
            guy.cur_num = j
            girl := &women[guy.pref[guy.cur_num]]
            girl.phone <- guy.id
            msg := <-guy.phone
            if msg == 1 {
                guy.cur_eng = guy.pref[guy.cur_num]
                break
            }
        }
        select {
        case <-guy.phone:
            guy.cur_eng = -1
        }
    }
}

func woman(id int, termi chan bool) {
    girl := &women[id]
    for {

        runtime.Gosched()
        select {
        case msg := <-girl.phone:
            if msg >= 0 {
                if girl.cur_eng == -1 {
                    men[msg].phone <- 1
                    girl.cur_eng = msg
                    termi <- true
                } else if girl.pref[girl.cur_eng] < girl.pref[msg] {
                    men[msg].phone <- 0
                } else {
                    men[msg].phone <- 1
                    men[girl.cur_eng].phone <- -10
                    girl.cur_eng = msg
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(8)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        men[i] = human{pref: [N]int{}, phone: make(chan int), cur_eng: -1, cur_num: -1, id: i}
        for j := 0; j < N; j++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &(men[i].pref[j]))
        }
    }
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        women[i] = human{pref: [N]int{}, phone: make(chan int), cur_eng: -1, cur_num: -1, id: i}
        for j := 0; j < N; j++ {
            t := 0
            fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &t)
            women[i].pref[t] = j
        }
    }
    termi := make(chan bool)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        go man(i)
        go woman(i, termi)
    }
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        <-termi
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d %d\n", i, men[i].cur_eng)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: The serial implementation of the program I made is [here](http://pastebin.com/PgPAUTAi). The time comparison shows both running in almost identical time (1.27s for serial, 1.30s for above one).

Also, the algorithm followed for the parallel implementation was made according to [this](http://www.oocities.org/vijayiyer01/docs/parallel_doc2.doc) as well as I could understand (I used goroutines as I didn't know how to use MPI).
Please feel free to suggest an alternative implementation (parallel) if possible.

The program above needs the following as input file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6jsnt965ZwrWlV1OE9LLVA1LUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why should this code "run faster"? Which parts do you expect to run in parallel on individual CPU cores? How much do you expect this parallelism to be? (Compared to the synchronised code parts and the snchronisation overhead?)

Comment: @Volker The program should run faster since in most cases, the proposals of men are being sent to different women, and those engagements are inherently independent of each other. If the go scheduler distributes the processes on separate threads, the only time they would be serialized would be when multiple men propose to the same women at the same time.

Comment: Cool. Now take a look at what actual computation is done in this "inherently independent" engagements **beside** channel sends/receives: Basically nothing. What is executing in parallel on different cores are a handful if `if`s and `for`s, a handful of integer assignments and arithmetic and memory access crossing cache lines (`human` is 'big', `man`and `woman` are big). To sum up: Your code consists of communications and synchronisation overhead with almost no CPU-local work (which I'd guess to not be CPU-cache local in addition). No speed gained.

Comment: @PallavAgarwal: I can't reproduce your results. I had to interrupt the program to end it. `go version devel +21efa7b Wed Nov 25 23:31:47 2015 +0000 linux/amd64`. `$ go build so.go && time ./so`. `GOMAXPROCS 8 NumCPU 4`. `^C`. `real 3m53.027s  user 0m0.003s  sys 0m0.003s`.

Comment: @peterSO Please check the EDIT in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the input file you provided would take that much time to be read by the program(via scanf per line).

Comment: Damn. Now I didn't expect that. I'll report back after checking with bigger files (and hopefully faster inputting method). Thanks for pointing out.